# Install correctly an website on nginx but showing 'Cannot GET /'

Tags: nginx, html

I am actually using a php website connect to another nodejs server like client side server side.
After many error and fix I get the error

`404 Cannot GET /`

Like the server want to get the index.php file but cant find it or get it .
I don't have any error or issues in the `/var/log/nginx/error.log` file .

Maybe there is other logs I need to see but i dont know where.

Server side :

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors'); 

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server, {cors: {origin: 'https://lapignatomarseille.com:443',   methods: ['GET', 'POST'],   credentials: true}});

// Serveur WebSocket
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Un client s\'est connecté');
  
    // Écoute les changements dans le dossier "Images"
    fs.watch('Images', { recursive: true }, (eventType, filename) => {
        if (eventType === 'change' || eventType === 'rename') {
          // Émet un événement 'imageUpdated' aux clients connectés
          io.emit('imageUpdated', { filename });
          setTimeout(function() {io.emit('MenuOk',{ filename });}, 500);
        }
    });

  // Gérer la déconnexion du client
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Un client s\'est déconnecté');
  });
});

// Serveur HTTP pour l'application web
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Serveur HTTP démarré sur le port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Client script side :

```
<script>
    // Connexion WebSocket côté client pour les utilisateurs
    const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000'); // Mettez à jour l'URL du serveur WebSocket

    // Écoute des événements 'imageUpdated'
    socket.on('connect', (e) => {
        console.log('Client connecté ');
    });

    socket.on('imageUpdated', (data) => {
        console.log('Image mise à jour:', data.filename);

        // Commentez ou supprimez la ligne suivante pour éviter le rechargement automatique
        document.location.reload()
    });
    </script>
```

There is the nginx conf file for lapignatomarseille.com.conf :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name lapignatomarseille.com www.lapignatomarseille.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/lapignatomarseille.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/lapignatomarseille.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/lapignatomarseille.com/chain.pem;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;

  # Autres configurations SSL...

  location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080;
  server_name lapignatomarseille.com www1.lapignatomarseille.com;
  root /home/lapignatomarseille/htdocs/lapignatomarseille.com;

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  index index.php index.html;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 443;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:18001;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "
error_log=/home/lapignatomarseille/logs/php/error.log;
memory_limit=512M;
max_execution_time=60;
max_input_time=60;
max_input_vars=10000;
post_max_size=64M;
upload_max_filesize=64M;
date.timezone=UTC+1;
display_errors=off;";
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}
```

What can I do to make the website visible when I go on the url ?
I dont know what can i show you so tell me and I update the question.

Thanks for reading !

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say here.

Comment: My english is maybe that bad ? I try to say that my nginx server is correctly install but my page in html isn't appear when I go on lapignatomarseille.com .

Comment: I don't know how the PHP server relates to the node.js server. I don't know where the HTTP requests originate, or how you expect the request which resulted in a 404 to be routed, nor how many hosts are involved in this exchange, whether the ONLY log you looked at relates to proxy in front of the php server or the node.js server or both. I don't know what the rest of your config looks like. I can tell that the the two (tiny) sample of config come from an nginx and node.js server - but that you couldn't even be bothered to tell anyone that makes me wonder what exactly is going on.

Comment: I uptdate the question I think it's bette. I am sorry i dont know how to setup use but i have to learn it .

Comment: Why is your proxy pass to proxy_pass http://localhost:8000. The other part with root directory is running on 8080

Comment: Thanks it work well better know I didn't expect it was that easy but thanks !